# Ratio of position error of orbiter to the size of the orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion

This is an assignment question for online AP physics. As if it isn't already tough. This question is killing me. I even asked my physics teacher from last year and my calculus teacher. It stumped them, too. I would show some kind of attempt at solving the question, but I've got nothing. I don't even understand how to begin solving this.

The question is:

> The space shuttle tracking system predicts the position of the shuttle orbiter with an accuracy that varies between 30 m and 100 m. Its orbital radius is slightly larger than the radius of the Earth (average orbit altitude is 340 km). What, approximately, is the ratio of the position error to the size of the shuttle’s orbit? The orbiter is approximately 37 m long and 17 high. ($R_{Earth} = 6378$ km)`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused what the question is asking. What does "size of the shuttle's orbit" mean? Does it mean the height above Earth's surface? Does it mean the radius of the orbit? If it's the second one, can't you just say it's $65:6718\approx 1:103$?

Comment: You and me both... I'd assume that it's asking for the circumference. Would that make sense?

Comment: Maybe? Try looking up the definition of "size of orbit". This does seem more like a question of English language than physics, though I think that's the AP physics question's fault for being ambiguously worded.